# Twelve numbers omitted

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

This is the beginning of a simple sequence.
NO Computers or special knowledge are required.
Insert the missing numbers. Explain how the sequence was generated.
Note: the line breaks can be ignored, they are only for readability.

> 1
> 2 ? 2 2 2
> 3 3 ? ? 3
> 4 ? 4 4 4
> 5 ? ? 5 ?
> 7 ? 7 7 7
> 8 8 ? ? ? ? 8…

(A small clue may be hidden...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sequence is

> The number of consonsants in the counting numbers: one, two, three,  ...

See

> oNe = 1
>  TWo = 2, THRee = **3**, FouR = 2, FiVe = 2, SiX = 2
>  SeVeN = 3, eiGHT = 3, NiNe= **2**, TeN = **2**, eLeVeN = 3
>  TWeLVe = 4, THiRTeeN = **5**, FouRTeeN = 4, FiFTeeN = 4, SiXTeeN = 4
>  SeVeNTeeN = 5, eiGHTeeN = **4**, NiNeTeeN = **4**, TWeNTY = 5, TWeNTY oNE = **6**
>  TWeNTY TWo = 7, TWeNTY THRee = **8**, TWeNTY FouR = 7, TWeNTY FiVe = 7, TWeNTY SiX = 7
>  TWeNTY SeVeN = 8, TWeNTY eiGHT = 8,  TWeNTY NiNe= **7**, THiRTY = **5**, THiRTY oNe = **6**,  THiRTY TWo = **7**,  THiRTY THRee = 8

Comment: Nice job, rot13(V gubhtug gur fhogyr uvag AB P jnf eryngrq gb Ebzna ahzrenyf, ohg vg zhfg'ir orra ahzore bs pbafbanagf gura)

Comment: @Prim3numbah rot13(Qb lbh yvxr pngf?)